# MVC dropdownlist for string value not ID

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

Is there any way to create a dropdown list in MVC that gives a string value to the variable not just the ID?  Everything I have seen on dropdownlist sets it up so that the name displays in the dropdown, but the variable always gets the ID value.  Is there any way to set that up so that the variable gets a string value?

Comment: Make the ID = name and the name = name. That way what is displayed is the same as the "value" or "id" of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

if you are wanting to select the id and get a value what @Jack has suggested will work great.  If you are wanting to get the Text that was selected instead of the value you can do that with jquery

```
$('.dropdown').change(function(){
     var result = $('.dropdown').text();
});
```

.val() will give you the value that was selected and .text() will give the text that was selected.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what you are asking for..

You can create a new instance of SelectList and the first argument is the List you are wanting to display in your dropdown. The second argument is the property you want to use for your option tags value, and the third argument is the property you want to use to populate the text inside of your option tag.

In this example I am using ID for the Value, but you would actually choose whatever property your string value is.

Controller Code

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   testDB.ContactTypes.Load();
   // "ID" is the property that we want to use for our option value
   // "Name" is the property that we want to use for the text inside of our tag
   ViewBag.ContactTypes = new SelectList(testDB.ContactTypes.Local.ToList(), "ID", "Name");
   return View();
}
```

Razor

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContactType , (SelectList)ViewBag.ContactTypes)
</div>
```